# Android application files

Tags: android

Is there a way to programatically get the path to the databases/files an application uses instead of hardcoding "data/data/mypackage.com/database.db" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For files: [`Context.getFileStreamPath()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) (alternatively, [`Context.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) for the whole directory).

For databases: [`Context.getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String))